# php.ini wrong path?

Tags: php

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File   C:\php\php.ini
```

I installed php on my windows server 2008 box. I'm pretty sure this path. Any ideas how to correctly fix this issue ?

Comment: What *is* the issue exactly? Is it loading the wrong ini file?

Comment: Well, When i'm trying to open a file, a warning says that the timezone is not set. I tried to fix this by setting a timezone in the php.ini file. But this doesn't seem to have any changes on the file. And i read by issues concerned php ini path being not correctly configured when php is being installed on a windows box.

Comment: If you do a `phpinfo()`, which php.ini does it show to you as the loaded one?

Comment: in C:\Windows there's no php.ini

Comment: Which php.ini file did you change the setting in? Did you restart the server after changing it?

Comment: Start>All Programs>PHP>php.ini. And yes, I did restart my server after changing it.

Comment: That is not a physical file path, but a shortcut - the file is in a physical directory somewhere. Which one is it? (Right-click the link and select "Properties")

Comment: That's the physical path: C:\php\php.ini. "fopen(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function". That's the error i'm getting although i did change the timezone correctly.

Comment: What code are you using to set the time zone?

Comment: I opened the php.ini in notepad and changed the timezone to: ;date.timezone = "Asia/Beirut"

Comment: You need to remove the semicolon, that comments out a line  in php.ini

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working now. Sorry for not posting the path right away : ].

Comment: No problem, you were working in the right file after all. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I opened the php.ini in notepad and changed the timezone to: ;date.timezone = "Asia/Beirut"

You need to remove the semicolon, which is the comment character in php.ini.